# Capture statistics of Low Memory crashes in iOS using exception handlers

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, low-memory

(This question is not about responding to low memory warnings in UIViewController)

In the same way that you can use the uncaught exception handler, and the signal handler to capture these events before the app dies, can you do this for Low Memory crashes?

crittercism.com claim "We capture all crashes that occur due to unhandled exceptions, low memory warnings, and signals." They are closed source, so I can't see what they are doing - and I haven't plugged in their SDK yet to verify their claim.

I've never seen any code that captures Low Memory crashes. Has anyone else/

Comment: No, I have not ever seen code to capture any data at the time the Apple OS decides your app has consumed too much memory and must die (no signals / exceptions raised).  :(  However...  In the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` I thought there were 3 levels of memory warnings before it dies, but that is not at the time of death.  +1 for question.  Hope somebody has a good answer, but I wouldn't hold my breathe.

Comment: Yup, but you can't publicly query the current memory level.

Comment: I wonder if you can...  If nothing else, perhaps redirect stdout or stderr to capture the log and parse it.  I know.  ewwww...  :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of `didReceiveMemoryWarning` of the `UIViewController`?
This is the information you get. If you free up enough space your app won't crash.

Comment: I was not sure what you're looking for. This is related information that might help some beginners.

Comment: Fair enough. I want to capture statistics of when the app dies from Low Memory, not the warnings. I've updated my question and title to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, launchd simply kills off processes with excessive memory usage. A signal handler for KILL/9 should catch those.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I'll have another look at the signal handler and see what's generated.

Comment: I am having the same issue, however, in signal.h: `#define SIGKILL 9 /* kill (cannot be caught or ignored) */`

Comment: There is:  `#define SIGTERM 15 /* software termination signal from kill */`